# how to use bibtex in IET Electronics letter Latex template?

Tags: bibtex, templates, bibitem

IET Electronics Letter template uses **bibitem** for reference. However, I want to use BiBtex file (.bib) i.e. a separate file for reference. Please suggest how I can use .bib file in the Latex file?

Answer (score 3):

Find the iet.bst file in the following archive:

http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip

Then use this style along with your .bib file to get the references in IET style.

```
\bibliographystyle{iet}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

### EDIT

Here is a modified version for IET Electronic letters:
[iet.bst](https://github.com/knidhin/iet-el_bib/blob/master/iet.bst)

Comment: Thanks @nidhin. Actually, IET Electronics Letter has different from IET journal. Anyway, I have tried what you have suggested but every reference comes in three different lines (1st line- Author, 2nd- Title, 3rd - other info). They are coming in continuous order.

Comment: Thanks for the modified file of 'iet.bst'. However, there is still one issue. Last author name should come after 'and' in reference. If it possible kindly modify that file for this 'and'.

Comment: @ChandanGautam Are you sure about that. I didn't see 'and ' in the template. Please see the word document here:http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/el/author-guide#manuscript

Comment: It seems MS word has slightly different format of reference. However, when you open Latex format of EL then 'and' is used. https://www.theiet.org/resources/journals/eletters/latex-files.cfm

Comment: @ChandanGautam Included 'and'. https://github.com/knidhin/iet-el_bib/blob/master/iet.bst

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working perfectly fine....