# An extra ",(" in the reference of a misc item

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I encountered this extra ".(," while adding the following misc item while using the BibTex in the Texmaker.

```
@misc{xxx,
author  = "{xxx}",
title         = {xxx},
year          =  {xxx},}
```

[image]

The style selection macro is as follows, which is from this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459248/how-to-use-bibtex-in-iet-electronics-letter-latex-template):

```
\bibliographystyle{iet}
\bibliography{xxx.bib}
```

Could you please help me to eliminate this "(."?

Comment: Please provide compilable code containing just the necessary content to trigger the problem ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)).

Comment: I think this is an `iet.bst` bug! Send a bug report: https://github.com/knidhin/iet-el_bib/blob/master/iet.bst